# How to add margin right to table

Tags: html, css

I have following html:

```
<table width="100%;>
        <tr><hr style="width:100%;"></hr></tr>
        <tr>
            <span style="float:left">abc</span>
            <span class="noindex" style="float:right">PageID</span>
        </tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>Some text here...</tr>
</table>
```

I want to add 100px margin from right of the screen. i tried adding margin-right and removing width =100% it is not working.

Comment: Your HTML is all wrong.

Comment: where are you're `<td>`s?, and `<br>|<hr>` inside `<table>`?

Comment: 1) Your table style is missing a closing quotation mark 2) You're using a closing hr tag which is unnecessary (it should be self closing with /). 3) You have no table cell tags (td).

Comment: You forgot the closing quotation mark in for the `width` property in the `<table>` tag, where I also think that you meant `<table style="width:100%;">`. You put stuff between `<tr>` tags without using any `<td>` tags. `<tr>` only means "table row;" you need to put in the `<td>` tags in order to define table cells. Finally, I don't understand why you would put a `<br/>` between two table rows.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

margin-right will not work if you set width to 100%.
What you could do is :

1. wrap table in a div tag. add margin to div
2. set table width to 100%

**UPDATED**
If you are creating a page layout, then you should be using divs instead of tables. Tables are appropriate for data display (like custom grid style view).

```
<div>
    <div style="margin-right:100px">
        <table style="width:100%">
            //your table
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually i just removed the table and kept div that worked.

Comment: I had to make the containing div `display: inline-block`

Comment: It worked for me, I removed the width 100% of the table and then put the margin right on the table. Then bam!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add td tags and you forget to close width atribute:

```
<table width="100%" style="margin-right:100px">
    <tr><td><hr style="width:100%;"></hr></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <span style="float:left">abc</span>
        <span class="noindex" style="float:right">PageID</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Some text here...</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the question asks for `margin-right`, not `margin-left`

Comment: @sdaau I change it to margin-right

Answer (score -5):

Just use this

```
<table width="100%" style="margin-right:100px;">
    <tr><hr style="width:100%;"></hr></tr>
    <tr>
        <span style="float:left">abc</span>
        <span class="noindex" style="float:right">PageID</span>
    </tr>
    <br/>
    <tr>Some text here...</tr>
  </table>
```